# CORSAIR Strafe Causing No Beep/Video POST Loop?

Tags: boot, ssd, clone, clonezilla, nvme

> If this is the wrong Stack Exchange to post this in, please let me know so I can ask the correct community.

Today I successfully cloned a Windows 10 installation from an HDD to a Samsung 980 NVMe SSD in my work PC (HP Z240 SFF) via Clonezilla. This was a bodacious performance boost as the HDD was approaching 4 years old. The computer successfully booted and I spent some time admiring how quickly all my programs loaded. Without making any changes, I shutdown my PC to go about installing Samsung’s NVMe drivers (I needed to switch from RAID mode to AHCI in the BIOS for the driver’s installer to detect the drive). Before I could do this however, the computer failed to enter POST (from my POV).

My monitors never turned on, CD & HDD activity halted abruptly shortly after startup, and I got no beep codes. The computer would sometimes attempt to reboot itself, other times it would just sit there idling and doing nothing. My first fear was that I fried a component as I had left my case open through this process. I spent my afternoon removing and readding all components in different combinations, removing the CMOS battery, you get the idea. I was relieved when I removed all my RAM and got beep codes, but nothing seemed to fix my problem.

In a final desperate measure, I unplugged my CORSAIR Strafe Keyboard and to my amazement my computer booted and passed POST! I reassembled the computer and booted with the KB unplugged and it passed POST again. This keyboard has two USBs, so I tried plugging just one into the computer. When I booted, the PC failed to POST! I then switched to the other USB and to my continued astonishment the computer passed POST once more.

This keyboard has been plugged into my computer through countless POSTs for years without causing a problem. I couldn’t even believe a keyboard can prevent a computer from POSTing. Does anybody have any idea why this might be happening??? Especially considering the PC successfully booted once before these symptoms appeared.

My only guess is it has something to do with my cloning process. During the process, I converted my disk to GPT via MBR2GPT. To do this, I needed to remove a partition to make room for the generated EFI partition during the conversion. I backed up my HP_TOOLS partition via Clonezilla, deleted it via Diskpart in Windows PE, and restored it again after the conversion was complete via CZ. I suspect this might be related as I noticed the Windows logo that appears during boot disappeared upon deletion of the partition and didn’t return after restoring it.

My other suspicion as I write this is that I have an SD Card reader with a Canon camera’a SD Card loaded in it plugged into the KB’s USB outlet. This has never been a problem before though and unfortunately I have left work and cannot test this hypothesis until Monday.

If anyone has any ideas I’d really appreciate your thoughts!